# how to compare two columns in dataframe and update a column based on matching fields

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two dataframe as shown below

```
|a|b|c|
|1|2| |
|4|5| |
|7|8| |
```

2nd dataframe is

```
|a_1|b_1|
|1  |5  |
|4  |2  |
|7  |8  |
```

I want to compare two common columns (a,a_1) and update the 3rd column in my 1st dataframe. Expected output is shown below

```
    |a|b|c|
    |1|2|5|
    |4|5|2|
    |7|8|8|
```

Is there a code to match common column and populate 3rd column?

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70958336/17991769
The problem looks similar to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

d1={
    "a":(1,4,7),
    "b":(2,5,8),
    "c":(0,0,0)
}

d2={
    "a_1": (1, 4, 7),
    "b_1": (5, 2, 8)
}

df1=pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(d2)

# Iterate through each entry in a and compare it to a_1
for i in range(len(df1["a"])):
    for j in range(len(df2["a_1"])):
        if df1["a"][i] == df2["a_1"][j]:
            df1["c"][i] = df2["b_1"][j]
```

Comment: Actually the column 'c' is already given in the dataframe i need to update the column not create a new column @Carsten Linder

Comment: then you can exchange the line: c_col_list.append(df2["b_1"][i])
which something like this: df1["c"][i]=df2["b_1"][i]

Comment: I am getting "KeyError: 0" when i try the above method @Carsten Linder

Comment: this is weird, the code works for me. KeyError simply means that pandas is not finding what you are searching for. One last option would be to use df1.get("c")[i]=df2.get("b_1")[i] instead of c_col_list.append(df2["b_1"][i])

Comment: Say my columns length is not matching in both the dataframe in such cases this code works?

Comment: If both dataframes have different lengths, than you need to adjust this line:
for i in range(len(df1["a"])):
Here you need to input the dataframe which is shorter than the other one. E.g. if df1 has a column length of 5 while df2 has only 3, then the code should use len(df2["a_1"]).

Comment: I have updated the code. Now the length of both dataframes should no longer matter. I have done this by using 2 for loops.